# AngularJS: Development and switching backends using Gulp

Tags: angularjs, gulp, gulp-watch

I need to switch my application server backend during development. Currently, the server is hard-coded in a module as a string. 
I was looking around for a good way to switch the server using gulp.

I am unsure how to achieve something like `gulp watch localhost` or `gulp watch devserver`, where the last argument denotes the backend server?

Comment: What are you using for your backend?

Comment: It's a JBOSS server with a resteasy interface

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have a configuration file for every different config, for example `dev.constant.js` and `local.constant.js`.

Each of these files contains an angular constant wich holds your current config, including your backend's url:

```
angular
    .module('myFancyModule')
    .constant('config', {
        backendUrl: 'https://my.backend.com/api/'
    });
```

Using `yargs` and `gulp-if`, you can check if a flag (e.g. `--dev`) is set and add the corresponding config file to the stream using `gulp-add-src`.

Another, more safe way is, to copy the particular config file to a file called `config.constant.js` once.

```
var argv = require('yargs').argv;
var fs = require('fs-extra');

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    if(argv.dev) {
        fs.copySync('./config/dev.constant.js', './config.constant.js');
    }

    //Your watch task here
}
```

Doing it this way, you are able to change your configuration very quick and easy. You could use this for builds and deploys as well, if you're doing them via gulp.

Comment: Thank you, will try that and if positive mark your answer